# HTMLPurifier Linkify broke when upgrading from 4.2 to 4.4

Tags: php, composer-php, htmlpurifier

Today I installed [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) and installed [HTMLPurifier](https://packagist.org/packages/ezyang/htmlpurifier), which replaced my old zipped download. This moved my version from 4.2 to 4.4

This code now no longer works:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href|title],em,strong,b,i,s,p'); 
$config->set('AutoFormat.Linkify', true); 
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$do = is_null($comment) ? $this->comment : $comment;
$clean = $purifier->purify($do);

debug($clean);
```

If I remove the composer autoload, and reference back to the old library, it works. This is on a string that includes `http://www.google.com` in it. But `$clean` is identical to `$do`

**edit**
Apparently, downloading through composer, the `HTMLPURIFIER_PREFIX` constant wasn't being created, and it wasn't loading the *.ser file (even though it existed. This is defined in `library/HTMLPurifier/Bootstrap.php`, but that file isn't included anywhere (therefore not defining, therefore not working).

**edit2** Looks like in my case it doesn't play nice with Composer. It didn't include the `Bootstrap.php` file at all. Had to manually call `HTMLPurifier_Bootstrap::registerAutoload();` from my app, and it's working better. Nice work me. More info [here](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/pull/10)

Comment: You should add those edits as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, as I said above, that the problem is related to Composer <-> HTMLPurifier interacting, and not properly loading the `Bootstrap.php` file correctly. Manually calling `HTMLPurifier_Bootstrap::registerAutoload();` seems to have fixed it for now.